# How to install and run Scilab manually?

Tags: software-installation, scilab

Firstly, I saw topics such as 'How to install manually a software...' but it did not solve my problem. I've downloaded Scilab 5.4.1 from the official website and I extracted the `.tar.gz` file into:

`/home/scilab-5.4.1`

I then tried the commands below, but they gave several errors:

```
$ cd scalib-5.4.1
$ configure        @1
$ make             @2
$ make install     @3
```

these gave the following messages in the terminal:

```
@1: configure: command not found
@2: make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
@3: make: *** No rule to make target `install'.  Stop.
```

I tried following commands:

```
$ cd scilab-5.4.1
$ cd bin
$ scilab
```

which gave the message:

```
The program 'scilab' is currently not installed.  You can install it
by typing: sudo apt-get install scilab
```

Comment: Does't change ! same error :(

Comment: I don't understand your mean ! Because i'm newbie :) `usr/local/src/` is empty! There is no configure directory !

Comment: Why dont you install it with `sudo apt-get install scilab`?

Comment: Ubuntu repository Scilab is't update :( Ver 3.5.5

Comment: Any suggestion.. ?

Comment: I disagree: the version in USC is up to date to the latest -stable- release. And it is not 3.5.5: packagename in Ubuntu is scilab-cli 5.4.1-1~exp1.

Comment: @Rinzwind, Your right, I'd mistake...

Comment: mine didn't open so i tried to type on terminal sudo scilab then my password,
then it worked

Comment: Note the typo in the first set of commands: `scalib` for `scilab`.

If you downloaded binaries, no need to run configure and make.

If you downloaded the source, instead of `configure`, run `./configure`.  

If either case, once you have the Scilab binaries of once you have built Scilab from sources, after `cd scilab-x.y.z` and `cd bin`, you need `./scilab` instead of just `scilab`. Or, better, from anywhere, type `/home/scilab-x.y.z/bin/scilab`. Even better, create a symbolic link: `sudo ln -s /home/scilab-x.y.z/bin/scilab /usr/local/bin` and then just run `scilab` from anywhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I just tried installing it, an it worked OK.  Here what I did: To install, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo apt-get install scilab
```

After the installation was done, I searched for scilab in dash, and clicked on it

[image]

After I clicked on it, it opened, and I checked the version, and it was 5.4.1

Hope that helps.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Your terminal command should work, but with the following change:

```
$ cd scilab-5.4.1
$ cd bin
$ ./scilab
```

Note the "dot-slash" before "scilab".  "Dot" is the current working directory.  Your shell was looking for scilab in all of the directories in your PATH environment variable, and not finding it, suggested that you needed to install the package. Do:

```
echo $PATH
```

on the command line and you will see which directories are searched.

This is a really common mistake - after a while, including the dot-slash will be second nature.  Note you can also include the path structure in the command line launch:

```
$ cd scilab-5.4.1
$ ./bin/scilab
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

### Ubuntu 16.04 LTS:

Once you have downloaded scilab, go to directory in terminal by pressing <kbd>Crtl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>, Unzip the package, go to the directory containing scilab.
Go to bin and run the command

```
$ ./scilab
```

Scilab 6.0.0

[image]

---

```
akhilesh_k@akhilesh:~/Programs$ cd sc*
akhilesh_k@akhilesh:~/Programs/scilab-6.0.0$ cd bin
akhilesh_k@akhilesh:~/Programs/scilab-6.0.0/bin$ ./scilab
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also just download the version for linux and simply click the binary in `scilab/bin/scilab`. It should work.

Answer (score 0):

**Installing Scilab manually**

**Step 1:** Open Terminal <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

**Step 2:** Check the architecture of your system

Use the command

**uname -m**

You will typically get:

**`i686 / i586 / i386`**

for 32-bit

and

**`x86_64`**

for 64-bit.

This helps you to choose the right scilab software for you. Now go to [scilab download page](http://www.scilab.org/download/latest) Depending upon the type of architecture you need to download the right package for you. Mine is 32 bit

[image]

most probably the software you download is generally downloaded in the following directory `/home/<your user name>/Downloads`

**Step 3:** Now once again open the terminal.
Enter the following commands

`cd /usr/local/`

`mkdir scilab`

This creates a scilab folder. It is here you are going to install the package. if you wish you can choose some other place also

`cd /home/<your user name>/Downloads`

`cp **Your Scilab Package** /usr/local/scilab`

`cd /usr/local/scilab`

**Step 4:** Extract the package by using the following command

`tar -xvzf **Your Scilab Package.tar.gz**`
`rm **Your Scilab Package.tar.gz**` This will remove the scilab Package

**Step 5:** For running Scilab use the following command

`/usr/local/scilab/scilab-6.0.0/bin`

`./scilab`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Make scilab launcher for scilab-6.0.0. Open the terminal and type:

```
sudoedit /usr/share/applications/scilab.desktop
```

Paste this in nano text editor:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=6.0.0
Name=Scilab
Comment=Scientific software package for numerical computations
NoDisplay=false
Exec=env UBUNTU_MENUPROXY=0 /usr/local/scilab-6.0.0/bin/scilab
Icon=/usr/local/scilab-6.0.0/share/icons/hicolor/48x48/apps/scilab.png
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=Application;Development;IDE
```

Now save and close nano text editor. Press the keyboard combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> and after that press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to save the file being edited in nano to its current location. Press the keyboard combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to exit nano.

Answer (score -1):

Ubuntu 18.04

```
sudo sed -i 's/jlatexmath-fop-1.0.6.jar/jlatexmath-fop-1.0.7.jar/' /usr/share/scilab/etc/classpath.xml
sudo apt install libcanberra-gtk-module libcanberra-gtk3-module
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to AskUbuntu! Care to improve your answer a little? Can you explain what those commands do and how they solve the problem?