# Upgrading Scilab from 5.5.0 to 5.5.1

Tags: scilab

Few days back I installed `Scilab` by command line

```
sudo apt-get install scilab
```

but it installed version 5.5.0 instead of the current one.
How can I install the latest one from command line?

Comment: @Parto and others, note that wont install the [latest version](http://www.scilab.org/download) (and the ones on using the tar.gz package are useless - http://askubuntu.com/questions/25961/how-do-i-install-a-tar-gz-or-tar-bz2-file may help there)

Answer (score 0):

You can install Scilab 5.5.1 by downloading the package directly for the scilab website and tar it on a location where you want to install scilab, using terminal window. Kindly follow the below steps

Linux 32 bits :

```
        $ wget http://www.scilab.org/download/5.5.1/scilab-5.5.1.bin.linux-i686.tar.gz
        $ cd <installation-path>
        $ tar xzvf scilab-5.5.1.bin.linux-i686.tar.gz # For 32 bits systems

Linux 64 bits :

        $ wget http://www.scilab.org/download/5.5.1/scilab-5.5.1.bin.linux-x86_64.tar.gz
        $ cd <installation-path>
        $ tar xzvf scilab-5.5.1.bin.linux-x86_64.tar.gz # For 64 bits systems
```

To launch Scilab:

```
    $ cd <scilab-path>/scilab-5.5.1
    $ ./bin/scilab
```

Comment: Hello, I have seen this question http://askubuntu.com/questions/297400/how-to-install-and-run-scilab-manually and followed the steps to install to scilab but that was 5.5.0 and the latest is 5.5.1. So I just want to upgrade. And second I have also downloaded from their website but when i launch it doesn't get installed though..or may be i don't know how to install it properly, you know, mentioning path in shell etc....